# Using ModelBuilder for closest facility analysis in ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst, closest-facility

I am building a model to iterate closest facility analysis for every building at an archaeological site, with the goal of generating a from-everywhere, to-everywhere aggregate traffic map. I have run the analysis manually on one "incident", and it works perfectly. Now I am trying to build a model to iterate through every building at the site. However, I cannot get the model to generate anything. I press "run entire model" and the dialogue says that it worked, but I can't find any outputs anywhere. I have specified a workspace (folder) and scratch space (folder). Below is a screenshot of the model as currently configured:

[image: Draft model]

Comment: As mentioned in the site tour, please ask only one question at a time.  That will ensure the best possible responses. https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Have you considered performing an [OD Cost Matrix Analysis](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00470000004r000000)?  I agree with @Fezter about the need for one question per question.

Comment: Yes but Cost Matrix doesn't output geometry of routes. Just a time matrix. I need the geometry.

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99961/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Network Analyst solvers only produce temporary results files/layers.

If you are running this from the model builder, you need to make sure the results are added to the display. If you are running this from a tool dialog box you need to expose it as a model parameter. See [this tutorial](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Exercise_6_Creating_a_model_for_route_analysis/004700000061000000/) and particularly the notes.

If you are looking to generate a feature class or shapefile as a result of the analysis, you will need to connect a select data and export or copy features tool to the output of the solver to save the results. This is also covered in the above tutorial near the bottom in the section *Configuring the model to save the results to disk*.

Note that an iterator runs *the entire model* for *each* iteration. So the part you've got here is likely to be a submodel to another model that has the iterator on it, and depending on how you build things you'll be looking at an append tool or something similar in the parent model to gather the outputs of the submodel into a single file. That's an entirely different question, but you'll want to look at the iterator help [this one in particular](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Iterate_Feature_Selection/00400000000s000000/) to get started.

Comment: After reviewing the "Configuring the model to save the results to disk, I was able to successfully run the model and output the result (the routes from the closest facility analysis) to a file geodb feature class. So I'll mark this as answered and ask the iteration question separately. Thx.